# Display all images from Sdcard

Tags: javascript, android, file, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using Phonegap 2.2.0.
i would like to get all images/photos/wallpapers from my android device with image saved path.
So far I have done is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, onFail);
    }

     function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("1.jpg", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readDataUrl(file);  
    }

    function readDataUrl(file) {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
           console.log("Read as data URL");
           console.log(evt.target.result);
           document.getElementById("smallImage").style.display='block'; 
           document.getElementById("smallImage").src = evt.target.result;   
        }; 
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function fail(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

the code give me only single image, but I want all images.
Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a DirectoryReader from the root FS and loop through all the entries looking for .svg files.

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    var reader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
    reader.readEntries(gotList, fail)l
}

function gotList(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        if (entries[i].name.indexOf(".svg") != -1) {
            uploadPhoto(entries[i].fullPath);
        }
    }
}
```